# Mac install ioncube with brew 7.2

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, ioncube

I've been looking around online and can't find the answer to my question.

I want to install ioncube on a mac with `PHP@7.2` via `home brew` however nowhere seems to explain how to do it.

There are a lots of instances where it says to download it and then:

`$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/ioncube/ioncube_loader_dar_7.2.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts/20090626/`

However, my issue is 1. permissions and 2. when `brew` changes location for the PHP install after an update I lose the ioncube.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: On the basis that sometimes the best solution is to do something different, if still stuck perhaps consider something other than homebrew, and if MacOS proves tricky to work with, you could always put Linux on a VM for a more suitable server environment.

Comment: Thought about doing that on a docker instance, but it just means using more resources on the system, which I didn't really want to do.